# Splitting a Content Database into two or three?

Tags: 2010, database, content-database

I have a SharePoint Farm in which the main Portal Web Application uses a single WSS_Content database, which has grown a lot to about 150 GB.

I know I can now put it offline and attach a new one, but I wonder if I can migrate existing site collections to shrink the size, and if it's possible for Site Collections in offline databases to still have new subsites added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 you can add additional Content Databases to your Web Application and then use the Move-SPSite PowerShell command to move site collections from one database to the other.

To add a Content Database: Goto Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Content Databases.  Select your web application and add a database.

To use the Move-SPSite PowerShell command: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx

Comment: Also, if you want to move content within Site Collections (from one Site Collection to another) you would need to to it manually or with third-party migration tools.  SharePoint only has the ability to move Site Collections between content databases out-of-the-box.

Comment: I guess this works provided you have your content split up into manageable site collections but if you've got a really large site collection then you're pretty much out of luck?

Comment: pigeon, that's where third party tools would be needed.